# Q: Configure CORS for Azure Static Web Apps (preview)

Tags: cors, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

I deploy artifacts like images, CSS and JavaScript bundles to an [Azure Static Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/?WT.mc_id=build2020_swa-docs-cxa) (Preview).
If I consume a JavaScript bundle from another site I get CORS errors. In the Azure configuration for Static Web App (Preview) there is no option to configure CORS. Any idea on how to configure CORS?

Comment: Is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services not relevant?

Comment: Regarding CORS, is it encountered when loading JavaScript files? Or do you implement a specific method?

Comment: Azure Static Web has a seamless security model of reverse proxy when calling the API, and no CORS configuration is required.

Comment: @sideshowbarker no, an Azure static web app seems different from a static site on Azure storage. Jason Pan, I am not calling an API, I use the site to host JavaScript and CSS bundles that I want to load from another web site (as a kind of CDN)

Comment: @SergevandenOever I conducted a test and did not reproduce your problem. If there is a problem with the operation steps, please let me know and we will solve your problem together.

Comment: I was able use @Keith answer. Before the answerCORS did not resolve via the tester, until I added the `staticwebapp.config.json` to the directory. I believe that @Keith is the proper answer.

Answer (score 6):

Configure the headers for the static application as discussed here:

[Configure Azure Static Web Apps | Global Headers | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#global-headers)

Creating `staticwebapp.config.json` in the root of the repo and adding the following config worked:

```
{
  "globalHeaders": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, OPTIONS"
  }
}
```

These are global headers, so not ideal, but in my case using "*" is fine.

---

Test if it works before and after a publish  to
[test-cors.org](https://www.test-cors.org/). Note that anything other than a `XHR status: 200` return is a failure.

Comment: Perfect! I solved my problem in an AngularJS project the steps you mentioned

Comment: Do i add this in github or in the azure static web app setting?

Comment: @Ziggy it is added as a file in the directory of the static website.

Answer (score -1):

***Suggestion***

1. If the operation is similar to mine, the cors problem still occurs, then I suggest you raise a support ticket on the portal. In theory, this problem should not exist.
2. If there is a problem with my reproduction steps, or if it is convenient for you, you can create and provide me with a link to your test file (for example, `test.js`), and I will test it again.

**PRIVIOUS**

After reading your question carefully again, I think this question shouldn't arise.

Normally, when we successfully publish our static web app program, we can directly access our static resources, such as `.js` files.

Currently you have an issue, so I tried it and wanted to reproduce your issue. If there is a step that is inconsistent with you, please let me know. We solve this problem together.

Here are my steps to reproduce:

1. Create the [myStaticWeb project](https://github.com/Jason446620/azureStaticWebapp), which contains the `css` and `js` folders, and the `index.html` file. As the main project of my Static web app, the `jquery.js` file in the js folder is used as the source file for cdn.

[image]

2. After publishing to github, the file directory is as follows.

   The path of the jquery.js file is `https://proud-dune-0b3b7a110.azurestaticapps.net/js/jquery.js`.

   You can also access it directly.

[image]

3. Create another static web app or .net core web app for testing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @json-pan, sorry for the late response, I just returned from vacation! Thanks for all the research you did. Example of the css and js files I want to access are on https://mango-river-020e4d803.azurestaticapps.net/index-slotted.html. For example the bundle file https://mango-river-020e4d803.azurestaticapps.net/build/sxa-umbrella-webcomponents.js, which I get CORS errors on when I access it from an other site. Can it be a configuration issue on the consuming side?

Comment: @SergevandenOever how did you get this working? I am doing the same thing as you (hosting javascript bundles on a static web app and referencing them from another site), but I don't get a CORS error with the file linked above and I do get a CORS error on requests to my own web app. Thanks

Comment: Oh, wait. If I use fetch() I still get the CORS error. But if I reference it in a script tag, I dont.

Comment: I had CORS issues with my static web site and was not able to resolve them until I used @Keith answer. I am not finding this to be an answer, but a real long comment. IMHO