# How to handle the CORS when the angular app running locally connects to the API in Production in a Azure Static Web App?

Tags: azure, cors, azure-static-web-app

I created a [Azure Static Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/overview) which contains an angular app and a **Azure Function API** in C#. It works in production. Now I want to run the angular app in my laptop at port 4200 at **http://localhost:4200** and connect to the **Azure Function API** in the production to do development and testing.

I get the following error when I try to connect:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://yyy.azurestaticapps.net/api/users_get/users' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I don't see any settings in Azure to set the **CORS**. How can I connect from my laptop to the Azure Function API in production without getting **CORS** errors?

Comment: Please see if this helps: https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/108#issuecomment-692401896.

Comment: There is no solution in that thread.

Comment: Similar question already logged https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63173497/q-configure-cors-for-azure-static-web-apps-preview

Comment: My app is not accessing any JavaScript files in other domain. I'm accessing the production Azure Function from the angular app in my local environment.